# Remove tuple from list of tuples if tuple's elements aren't in a list of strings

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm working on some code where I need to remove a tuple from a list of tuples if the tuple doesn't contain all strings in a separate list. I've got it working in a for loop, but I'm trying to improve the efficiency of my code. As an example, if I have

```py
list_of_tups = [('R', 'S', 'T'), ('A', 'B'), ('L', 'N', 'E'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
needed_strings = ['R', 'S', 'T']
```

I want to keep the following tuples in my list:

```py
[('R', 'S', 'T'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
```

This works in the following for-loop:

```py
for s in needed_strings:
    for tup in list_of_tups:
        if s not in tup:
            list_of_tups.remove(tup)
```

However, I'd like for this to be done via list comprehension. My attempts at doing this result in a list of tuples where *any* of the strings, not *all*, appear in the tuple.

Comment: Could you provide your attempts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `all` with a nested comprehension:

```
list_of_tups = [('R', 'S', 'T'), ('A', 'B'), ('L', 'N', 'E'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
needed_strings = ['R', 'S', 'T']

[t for t in list_of_tups if all(c in t for c in needed_strings)]
```

**result**

```
[('R', 'S', 'T'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
```

So long as the lists contain hashable items, an alternative that may be a little easier to read is to make `needed_strings` a `set`. Then you can use `issubset()`

```
list_of_tups = [('R', 'S', 'T'), ('A', 'B'), ('L', 'N', 'E'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
needed_strings = set(['R', 'S', 'T'])

[t for t in list_of_tups if needed_strings.issubset(t)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
list_of_tups = [('R', 'S', 'T'), ('A', 'B'), ('L', 'N', 'E'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
needed_strings =['R', 'S', 'T']
y=[x for x in list_of_tups if set(needed_strings).issubset(set(x))] 
print(y)
```

Output :

```
[('R', 'S', 'T'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
list_of_tups = [
    ('R', 'S', 'T'), 
    ('A', 'B'), 
    ('L', 'N', 'E'), 
    ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), 
    ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')
]
needed_chars = {'R', 'S', 'T'}  # using a set to speed up membership operations

# Append the tuple element from the list of tuples if the condition is met
list_of_tups_removed = [
    tup
    for tup in list_of_tups
    if any(c in needed_chars for c in tup)  # if any of the characters are present in needed_chars 
]

print(list_of_tups_removed)
```

Output:

```py
[('R', 'S', 'T'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
```

A list comprehension syntax can only be used to create a new list. It cannot be used to remove elements from an existing list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lambda` function and `set.issubset` to check if every element in `needed_strings` is in a given element of `list_of_tups` list and finally filter it out:

```
list_of_tups = [('R', 'S', 'T'), ('A', 'B'), ('L', 'N', 'E'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
needed_strings = ['R', 'S', 'T']
print(list(filter(lambda x: set(tuple(needed_strings)).issubset(x), list_of_tups)))
```

output:

```
[('R', 'S', 'T'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L'), ('R', 'S', 'T', 'L', 'N', 'E')]
```